# Stackdriver Dashboard there is not Share option for Charts based on custom data

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I can see Share option in drop-down menu for charts based on data from Stackdriver agent but I cannot see it for Charts based on Custom Metrics, Log Metrics.

Metrics from stackdriver agent: 
[Metrics from stackdriver agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KAA0.png)

Log Metrics, Custom Metrics:
[Log Metrics, Custom Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5TqT.png)

[Chart sharing documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/tips-and-tricks)

Is it possible to share these Charts?

Comment: There is a way to share log-based charts. 
Instead of log metrics creation I had to export the data to Pub/Sub topics and create Charts with the topics.